# Costom Joi validation message for Object.and()

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi

I have a schema that I want to validate using `Ojbect.and()`.

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    password: Joi.string().regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$/),
    access_token: [Joi.string(), Joi.number()],
    birthyear: Joi.number().integer().min(1900).max(2013),
    email: Joi.string().email(),
    nickname: Joi.string()
}).and('username', 'birthyear', 'nickname').without('password', 'access_token');
```

By default it return a validation error message like.
`"\"value\" contains [username] without its required peers [birthyear, nickname]"`

I want it to return a custom error message like.
`Username, Birthyer and Nick name all are required!`

For custom message say `nickname` I would do something like below
`Joi.string().messages({ 'string.base' : "Nickname should be string!"})`
So, I tried below, but It doesn't work.

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    password: Joi.string().regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$/),
    access_token: [Joi.string(), Joi.number()],
    birthyear: Joi.number().integer().min(1900).max(2013),
    email: Joi.string().email(),
    nickname: Joi.string()
})
.and('username', 'birthyear', 'nickname').without('password', 'access_token')
.messages({ 'Object.and' : "Username, Birthyear and Nick name all are required!"})
```

How can I do something same for `Object.and` validation error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message key `string.base` overrides string validation messages

In your case you should use `object.and`

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    password: Joi.string().pattern(/^[abc]+$/),
    access_token: [Joi.string(), Joi.number()],
    birthyear: Joi.number().integer().min(1900).max(2013),
    email: Joi.string().email(),
    nickname: Joi.string()
})
.and('username', 'birthyear', 'nickname').without('password', 'access_token')
.messages({ 'object.and' : "Username, Birthyear and Nick name all are required!"})
```

Comment: What I was missing `Object.and` was capitalizing. It has clearly mentioned in the doc I didn't notice that silly mistake.